# php - Nested Loop, Break Inner Loops and Continue The Main Loop

Tags: php, loops, nested, break, continue

I have the following loop and I want to `continue` the while loop when the check inside the inner loop has meet the condition. I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168578/break-inner-foreach-loop-and-continue-outer-foreach-loop) (*which is I applied in the following example*), but it is for `c#`.

```
    $continue = false;
    while($something) {

       foreach($array as $value) {
        if($ok) {
          $continue = true;
           break;
           // continue the while loop
        }

           foreach($value as $val) {
              if($ok) {
              $continue = true;
              break 2;
              // continue the while loop
              }
           }
       }

      if($continue == true) {
          continue;
      }
    }
```

Is PHP has its own built it way to `continue` the main loop when the inner loops have been `break`-ed out?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

After reading the comment to this question (*which was deleted by its author*) and did a little research, I found that there is also parameter for `continue` just like `break`. We can add number to the `continue` like so:

```
while($something) {

   foreach($array as $value) {
    if($ok) {
       continue 2;
       // continue the while loop
    }

       foreach($value as $val) {
          if($ok) {
          continue 3;
          // continue the while loop
          }
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think as you are not running the `continue` until you have processed the complete inner foreach it is irrelevant. You need to execute the `continue` in situ and not wait until the end of the loop.

Change the code to this

```
while($something) {

    foreach($array as $value) {
        if($ok) {
            continue;    // start next foreach($array as $value)
        }

        foreach($value as $val) {
            if($ok) {
               break 2;    // terminate this loop and start next foreach($array as $value)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**RE: Your comment**

```
while($something) {

    if($somevalue) {
        // stop this iteration
        // and start again at iteration + 1
        continue;    
    }


}
```

Comment: The real case is just to find a value and go for the next iteration of the `while` loop. So I made it like that. The comment for `continue` key in your `foreach` loop seem for me telling that it is continuing the `while` loop. Is that it?

Comment: No, `continue` just starts the _loop that it is used in_ from the next iteration

Comment: See additional info re your comment. I hope this is what you mean!